# Setting up Equations for Mixture Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

An automobile radiator contains 16 liters of antifreeze and water. This mixture is 30% antifreeze. How much of this mixture should be drained and replaced with pure antifreeze so that there will be 50% antifreeze?

I can obtain the answer using my own method of solving this problem, but the problem is that I need to set up equations for this, looking for help, thanks

Comment: I already know how to solve it I just need help setting up equations

Comment: You know, system of equations, a way of solving it

Comment: Deleted your comments Moo? ok then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can have a solution whatever the volume $V$ of mixture: suppose you replace a fraction $xV$ of mixture with the same volume of pure antifreeze. The total volume of pure antifreeze in the new mixture is
$\;0.3(1-x)V+xV=(0.3+0.7x)V$, hence the equation will be
$$0.3+0.7x=0.5$$

Comment: Oh, I see it now, thanks